# Python recursion RuntimeError

Tags: python, recursion

```
def f1():
    f1()
```

We all know that calling this function in Python will produce `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

I wrote its sligtly modified version:

```
def f2():
    try:
        f2()  #This line throws an error
    finally: #except works too
        f2()  #This line does not throw an error!
```

The second function runs forever without throwing `RuntimeError`. What's more, I was not able to stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> combination.

I dont understand why calling f2() does not throw `RuntimeError`. Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the stack fills up, it calls `f2` inside the `try` until it reaches the maximum recursion depth.

Once it's reached that, it raises a `RuntimeError`, which is handled by the `finally`

That in turn raises the same `RuntimeError`, but now to the earlier stack, which passes along to the `finally` call.

Inside there, it exceeds the maximum depth again.

When a `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised, the program moves on to the `finally` all the same, and doesn't exit.

It won't technically run forever, because there's only one `finally`. That said, (thanks to the comments), it allows exponentially more calls, which is pretty dang close to infinity. A recursion depth of 100 would turn into 2<sup>100</sup> == 1267650600228229401496703205376.

If it took 1ms per call, it would take **465 billion years** to complete. And that's just a depth of 100

Comment: i believe this'll end up being `O(n**n)` in the maximum number of stack frames actually.  so, quite a while.

Comment: I was just coming to that realization myself. Yikes!

Comment: or maybe `O(2**n)`, actually.  astronomical either way  :)

Comment: @Martijn, I don't think so. You can't enter the exact same `finally` unless you're in a bona fide loop.

Comment: Haha I will not wait till exception then. Thank you

Comment: [This experiment](http://pastebin.com/6yMgzrqR) indicates that the program does finish executing, but takes twice as long each time you increase the recursion limit by one. so O(2**n) is a good estimation.

Answer (score 4):

The exception is still being thrown, but *before Python can show it* you are calling `f2()` *again*.

So each time the exception is raised, you sneak in another call. That recursive call is allowed (because we are one step below the limit), we cross the limit, the exception is raised again, the `finally` handler sneaks in another call, almost ad infinitum.

`CTRL-C` doesn't end the program for the same reasons; an exception is raised (`KeyboardInterrupt`), but again the `finally:` handler sends you back into recursion.

*You are now falling at such a velocity you entered orbit around the interpreter.*

It all *does* end, but the `finally` handlers add an exponentially growing number of extra calls before the stack can fully unwind:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def f2(depth=0, final=0):
...     try:
...         print depth
...         f2(depth + 1, final)
...     finally:
...         print 'finally:', final
...         f2(depth, final + 1)
... 
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(5)
>>> f2()
0
1
2
3
finally: 0
finally: 0
2
finally: 1
finally: 0
1
2
finally: 1
finally: 1
1
finally: 2
finally: 0
0
1
2
finally: 1
finally: 1
1
finally: 2
finally: 1
0
1
finally: 2
finally: 2
0
finally: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in f2
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in f2
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in f2
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in f2
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Wish I could give another +1 for `You are now falling at such a velocity you entered orbit around the interpreter`

Comment: Will it run forever or it will finally raise an exception (after VERY long time as @mhlester suggests)?

Comment: @pbackup: it'll run forever. There is just one stack limit, not a square root of limits. You just keep 'recovering' then re-entering the problem by re-applying a `try`-`finally` handler.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You don't keep rerunning the same `f2` call. Try lowering the recursion limit and then testing it; you'll see that it actually does terminate.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, you are right; you do fall back eventually.